# Sum + Countifs formula not working

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, countif, array-formulas

I'm using Google Sheets and am trying to get this formula to work to give the me the following count:

Count when Column T = `Kenneth` AND Column U = (`Pending` OR `Contacted`) AND Column W has a date that falls between the dates shown in B14 and B15.

This is what I have so far:

```
=sum(countifs(Users!$T:$T,"Kenneth",Users!$U:$U,{"Pending","Contacted"},Users!$W:$W,">"&$B14,Users!$W:$W,"<="&$B15))
```

This is giving me the correct count for `Pending` alone but it is ignoring all the `Contacted` rows so somehow it is not recognizing that OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIFS (and SUMIFS) do not support array arguments for the conditions. You will need to resort to summation of COUNTIFS:

`=COUNTIFS(Users!$T:$T,"Kenneth",Users!$U:$U,"Pending",Users!$W:$W,">"&$B14,Users!$W:$W,"<="&$B15)+COUNTIFS(Users!$T:$T,"Kenneth",Users!$U:$U,"Contacted",Users!$W:$W,">"&$B14,Users!$W:$W,"<="&$B15)`

or a different approach, eg:

`=COUNTIF(FILTER(Users!$T:$T,(Users!$U:$U="Pending")+(Users!$U:$U="Contacted"),Users!$W:$W>$B14,Users!$W:$W<=$B15),"Kenneth")`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrayformula, you can sum the boolean values multiplied against each other.

```
=arrayformula(sum((T:T="Kenneth")*(U:U={"Pending","Contacted"})*(W:W>=B14)*(W:W<=B15)))
```

A boolean true is *1* and a false is *0*. Anything multiplied against a zero is zero so all conditions must be true to add another *1* for each row.

[image: Google-Sheets COUNTIFS with OR criteris]